# Remove all instance of attribute for image tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

As you can see in the img tag below, the first src attribute value contains a strange tag in itself. What is the best way to remove all the src attributes and their values for all of the img tags in my DOM?

```
<a href="https://www.prikkabelled.nl/feestverlichting-voor-de-achtertuin/"><img src="<img width="806" height="605" src="https://www.prikkabelled.nl/wp-content/uploads/Feestverlichting-voor-in-de-achtertuin.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="https://www.prikkabelled.nl/wp-content/uploads/Feestverlichting-voor-in-de-achtertuin.jpg 806w, https://www.prikkabelled.nl/wp-content/uploads/Feestverlichting-voor-in-de-achtertuin-152x114.jpg 152w, https://www.prikkabelled.nl/wp-content/uploads/Feestverlichting-voor-in-de-achtertuin-768x576.jpg 768w, https://www.prikkabelled.nl/wp-content/uploads/Feestverlichting-voor-in-de-achtertuin-253x190.jpg 253w, https://www.prikkabelled.nl/wp-content/uploads/Feestverlichting-voor-in-de-achtertuin-506x380.jpg 506w, https://www.prikkabelled.nl/wp-content/uploads/Feestverlichting-voor-in-de-achtertuin-600x450.jpg 600w, https://www.prikkabelled.nl/wp-content/uploads/Feestverlichting-voor-in-de-achtertuin-200x150.jpg 200w" sizes="(max-width: 806px) 100vw, 806px" /></a>
```

This is what I tried so far:

```
jQuery( "img.attachment-post-thumbnail.size-post-thumbnail.wp-post-image" ).attr( "src" ).removeAttr('src');
```

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Use [a PHP DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) instead.

Comment: I added my attempt at solving this

Comment: That looks more like a weird typo than containing "*a strange tag*."

Comment: I don't think it would be wise to edit the source file because it is part of the theme. What do you think?

Comment: First; solve the problem, then; write the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will be your solution. it finds and removes all the src attributes.

```
jQuery( "img.attachment-post-thumbnail.size-post-thumbnail.wp-post-image" ).find('src').removeAttr('src');
```

Comment: Do or do not, there is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove an attribute using `removeAttr()` in jQuery.

```js
$('img').removeAttr('src');
console.log($('img')[0])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://www.prikkabelled.nl/feestverlichting-voor-de-achtertuin/">
<img src="<img width="806" height="605" src="https://www.prikkabelled.nl/wp-content/uploads/Feestverlichting-voor-in-de-achtertuin.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="https://www.prikkabelled.nl/wp-content/uploads/Feestverlichting-voor-in-de-achtertuin.jpg 806w, https://www.prikkabelled.nl/wp-content/uploads/Feestverlichting-voor-in-de-achtertuin-152x114.jpg 152w, https://www.prikkabelled.nl/wp-content/uploads/Feestverlichting-voor-in-de-achtertuin-768x576.jpg 768w, https://www.prikkabelled.nl/wp-content/uploads/Feestverlichting-voor-in-de-achtertuin-253x190.jpg 253w, https://www.prikkabelled.nl/wp-content/uploads/Feestverlichting-voor-in-de-achtertuin-506x380.jpg 506w, https://www.prikkabelled.nl/wp-content/uploads/Feestverlichting-voor-in-de-achtertuin-600x450.jpg 600w, https://www.prikkabelled.nl/wp-content/uploads/Feestverlichting-voor-in-de-achtertuin-200x150.jpg 200w" sizes="(max-width: 806px) 100vw, 806px" /></a>
```